# why we use naming conventions in joomla?

Tags: joomla

I am new in joomla . my question is why we have to use naming conventions in joomla and which part of joomla delivered with this naming conventions ?
for example when we make a plugin we have to use the plg as a naming conventions for class name . why ? 
and I am confused how this class work without make any instance of it ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know those naming conventions have historical reasons, which I do not know exactly. They are useful to easily divide between modules, components and plugins, which are all available in Joomla!, what is different to wordpress and Drupal, where you have plugins and modules only.

The last time I have created a Joomla! component, the `com_` prefix is/was needed to locate and load the source code of that component, so necessary. If that is now replaced by the autoloader and namespaces, I guess one could omit it, but to hang on to the coding standards, I would recommend to keep on using it.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question from my friend @ [biswarupadhikari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997163/biswarupadhikari)

If you don't follow naming convention then how joomla will be able to understand which class joomla needs to call or which file joomla needs to include